# Ruby Gem Project -- Thor Generator Causing Read-only File System Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

As a personal project, I decided to write a minified-version of Ruby on Rails and upload it as a gem using Bundle called `railz_lite`.

Inside of my project, I was hoping to implement a Generator similar to `rails new`, which would create the necessary folders for a web app i.e. controllers/, views/, models/, etc.

To do so, I included Thor as a dependency, then created the following files:

```rb
require 'thor/group'

module RailzLite
  module Generators
    class Project < Thor::Group
      include Thor::Actions
      
      def self.source_root
        File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/templates"
      end
      
      def add_controllers
        empty_directory("controllers")
      end

      def add_models
        empty_directory("models")
      end

      def add_server
        template("server.rb", "config/server.rb")
      end

      def add_views
        empty_directory("views")
      end

      def add_public
        empty_directory("public")
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Inside the gem project's root folder, when I run `bundle exec railz_lite new`, the generator works just fine and the necessary files are created.

However, if I create a new project, puts my gem (railz_lite) in the Gemfile, run bundle install, then execute `bundle exec rails_lite new`, I am greeted with the following error:

```rb
.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/fileutils.rb:232:in `mkdir':
: Read-only file system @ dir_s_mkdir - /controllers (Errno::EROFS)
```

I suspect the error is because the `empty_directory` command is not referring to the root directory of the project I just created.  I am hoping that there is a simple way to fix this.

For further reference, the CLI script and class look as follows:

railz_lite

```rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'railz_lite/cli'

RailzLite::CLI.start
```

cli.rb

```
require 'thor'
require 'railz_lite'
require 'railz_lite/generators/project'

module RailzLite
  class CLI < Thor
    desc 'new', 'Generates a new RailzLite project'
    def new
      RailzLite::Generators::Project.start([])
    end
  end
end
```

Any solutions would be greatly appreciated!

Note: I am running this on macOS Catalina.

Answer (score 0):

So I found a solution after searching extensively through gem forums and looking at the Rails source code.

Inside of the generation I have to manually set the destination_root to the working directory of the project. The working directory can be found with `Dir.pwd`

```rb
require 'thor/group'

module RailzLite
  module Generators
    class Project < Thor::Group
      include Thor::Actions
      
      def self.source_root
        File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/templates"
      end

      def self.destination_root # this method fixes the problem!
        Dir.pwd # get the current project directory
      end
      
      def add_controllers
        empty_directory("controllers")
      end

      def add_models
        empty_directory("models")
      end

      def add_server
        template("server.rb", "config/server.rb")
      end

      def add_views
        empty_directory("views")
      end

      def add_public
        empty_directory("public")
      end
    end
  end
end
```